# Discord buttons side by side

Tags: discord

I made something using the discord-buttons module but I want to put the buttons side by side. What should I do?

My Code:

```js
await message.channel.send(gönder, { components: [row, row2, row3, row4]
});
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ks25.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one `ActionRow` instead of four. That is, pack all four of your button components into a single `ActionRow` object, and then pass that sole row to your components array.